# Pegar registro anterior - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Preciso trazer somente os registros onde o status anterior era `1`, mas que atualmente é `0`.

Tenho uma tabela chamada `solicitação` que contém um campo chamado `VencimentoPausado`, onde esse campo os valores são `1` ou `0`, ou seja, `1` `Chamados que estão em pausa` e `0` `Chamados que não estão em pausa`.
Quero trazer todos os chamados que não estão mais em pausa, ou seja, antes da movimentação era `1` e depois da movimentação é `0`.

Lembrando que se eu colocar na condição `vencimentpausado` = 0, ele vai trazer todos os chamados, mas eu quero trazer apenas os chamados que antes o status era 1.

## Tabela Solicitação

```
**Coluna**  **Tipo**
AmbienteID     int
AprovacaoRevisao    bit
CalcularVencimentoAprovacao bit
ChamadoIntegradoID  int
ConcluidoNoAtendimento  bit
ConcluidoPeloSistema    nchar
CustoTotal  numeric
DataAberturaSistema datetime
DataAlteracao   datetime
DataAprovacao   datetime
DataBaseReabertura  datetime
DataBaseSlaDinamico datetime
DataCancelamento    datetime
DataCompromisso datetime
DataEntendimento    datetime
DataPrevistaPriResp datetime
DataPrevistaRetorno datetime
DataRealFechamento  datetime
DataRealPriResp datetime
DataRealRetorno datetime
Descricao   varbinary
EPGerada    bit
FusoHorarioID   int
HorarioVeraoHistoricoID int
ImportadoAmbienteIntegrado  bit
Incidente   bit
IntegracaoConcluida bit
IntegracaoPausada   bit
MacProcID   int
MailPriRespEnviado  nchar
ModID   int
MotivoCompromissoID int
NatID   smallint
Natureza    nvarchar
NomeCliente nvarchar
Organiza    nvarchar
OrgID   int
OrgIDGrp    int
PermitePausarVencimento bit
PermiteReclassificarVencimento  bit
Produto nvarchar
ProID   int
Projeto nvarchar
ProjID  int
RecalculaVencimentoDataVisita   bit
ReplicadoAmbienteIntegrado  bit
Sequencia   numeric
SeveridadeID    int
SLAVlCalculado  int
SLAVlRevCalculado   int
SolAlterado nchar
solAprovado nchar
SolArqAtachado  nchar
SolArqNome  nvarchar
SolAssumido smallint
SolCalcularVencimento   nchar
SolCaminho  nvarchar
SolData datetime
SolDataConclusao    smalldatetime
SolDataFechamento   datetime
SolDataVisita   smalldatetime
SolEnviaEmailTramite    nchar
SolEnvioEmail   datetime
SolEstagioID    int
SolGrupoSAC nchar
SolicitacaoPai  int
SolID   int
SolIDCopia  int
SolIDInclusao   int
SolIDRef    nvarchar
SolNivel    int
SolNumTramite   int
SolOrigem   nchar
SolPerAlcada    int
SolPrioridade   smallint
SolQtdeReaberturas  smallint
SolQtdFilho int
SolQtdTarFilho  int
SolRetrabalho   nchar
SolRetrabalhoResp   nchar
SolStatus   tinyint
SolSugestao nchar
SolTempoTelefone    int
SolTipID    int
SolTipoVinculo  smallint
SolTitulo   nvarchar
SolVencimento   datetime
SolVerL int
SolVerO int
TempoCorridoSLADinamico bit
TempoGastoTotal int
TempoPriResp    int
TempoRestanteVencimento int
TempoSlaReabertura  int
TipoDescricao   nvarchar
TipoFechamentoAutomatico    int
TituloChamadoIntegrado  nvarchar
UsuCentrodeCusto    nvarchar
UsuIDAssociado  int
UsuIDAtendenteViaFone   int
UsuIDCliente    int
UsuIDDistribuidor   int
usuIDFilial int
UsuIDGrupoRespConclusao int
UsuIDInclusao   int
UsuIDMatriz int
UsuIDReclamante int
UsuIDReclamanteAssociado    int
UsuIDReclamanteDistribuidor int
usuIDReclamanteRepresentado int
usuIDRepresentado   int
UsuIDResponsavel    int
UsuIDSuporte    int
UsuIDUltimaAlteracao    int
UsuIDUltimoResp int
UtilizaSLADinamico  bit
ValorServico    numeric
ValorServicoCaminho numeric
ValorTotal  numeric
VencimentoChamadoIntegrado  bit
VencimentoInformadoManualmente  bit
VencimentoPausado   bit
VersaoL nvarchar
VersaoO nvarchar
```

Comment: Este "antes" supõe uma data !? Tente um exists em um subselect.

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/560413-n%C3%A3o-tenha-valor-posterior-sql-oracle/#comment-2235723    veja se ajuda.

Comment: ôpa Motta, não amigo, refere-se a um campo bit. Aceita só 1 ou 0

Comment: @RenanBessa: Se não há registro de histórico da movimentação, então não há como. A análise do log de transação de log seria uma possibilidade, mas de implementação trabalhosa. // Será necessário implementar o registro de alterações.

Comment: Em princípio só vejo solução se for cirado uma coluna de "data_de_operacao" na tabela , a solução ficaria com um trivial EXISTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um `WITH` para ordenar por solicitação e vincular a anterior e a próxima.

```
WITH timeline (SolID,
               ChamadoIntegradoID,
               Ordem,
               VencimentoPausado)
AS (
  SELECT s.SolID,
         s.ChamadoIntegradoID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.ChamadoIntegradoID
                           ORDER BY s.DataAberturaSistema) AS Ordem,
         VencimentoPausado
    FROM solicitacao s
)

SELECT atual.SolID,
       atual.ChamadoIntegradoID,
       atual.VencimentoPausado
  FROM timeline atual
       INNER JOIN timeline anterior ON anterior.ChamadoIntegradoID = atual.ChamadoIntegradoID
                                   AND anterior.Ordem = (atual.Ordem - 1)
 WHERE atual.VencimentoPausado = 0
   AND anterior.VencimentoPausado = 1
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM timeline proximo
                   WHERE proximo.ChamadoIntegradoID = atual.ChamadoIntegradoID
                     AND proximo.Ordem > atual.Ordem;
```

---

Na `query` acima:

- O `WITH` é usado para agrupar o conteúdo que será utilizado na obtenção e filtragem dos dados;
- O `ROW_NUMBER` com `PARTITION BY` por `codigo_chamado` atribuirá um sequencial dentro de cada agrupamento e o `ORDER BY` garantirá que esse sequencial obedecerá a ordem de inserção;
- Utilizando os dados resultantes, um `INNER JOIN` é realizado com os dados da tabela realizando a junção entre o registro atual e o anterior;
- A restrição da coluna `VencimentoPausado`é feita no `WHERE`;
- Uma cláusula `NOT EXISTS` é utilizada para verificar se o registro atual é o último válido.

---

> [`WITH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175972(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> Especifica um conjunto de resultados nomeado temporário, conhecido como uma CTE (expressão de tabela comum). Ela é derivada de uma consulta simples e definida no escopo de execução de uma única instrução SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE ou DELETE. Esta cláusula também pode ser usada em uma instrução CREATE VIEW como parte da instrução SELECT que a define. Uma expressão de tabela comum pode incluir referências a si mesma. É o que chamamos de expressão de tabela comum recursiva.

---

> [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna o número sequencial de uma linha em uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, iniciando em 1 para a primeira linha de cada partição.

---

> [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188336(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Especifica uma subconsulta a ser testada quanto à existência de linhas.

Comment: Olá @Sorack, a tabela existe somente a coluna solid que refere-se ao número do chamado, sendo assim, tirei o s.codigo_solicitacao e o s.codigo_chamado e deixei apenas o s.solid que é da tabela solicitação.Porém, não retornou nenhum registro.

Comment: @RenanBessa você pode colocar a estrutura completa das duas tabelas na sua pergunta para que possamos verificar melhor como poderíamos fazer a `query`?

Comment: ôpa @Sorack. Editei lá a pergunta. Veja se falta mais algo para que eu possa inseri.

Comment: @RenanBessa alterei a resposta, veja se lhe atende

Comment: esse chamadoIntegradoID não armazena nada. O campo que diz o numero do chamado é o Solid e o dataaberturasistema é o soldata, sendo assim, eu alterei o chamadoIntegradoID por solid e o dataaberturasistema pelo soldata, mas ainda n.

Comment: @RenanBessa consegue colocar uma amostra dos dados para tentarmos achar o problema?

Comment: e a todos os amigos daqui que me auxiliaram. Consegui resolver através do log mesmo. Implementei um histórico e deu tudo certo.

Answer (score 2):

## Edição

Olhando melhor essa pergunta, hoje, ela não parece muito clara. Eu só queria acrescentar que para consultar valores anteriores/prévios, em outra linha, pode-se usar as funções de janela (*windowing*).

Exemplo

**[Simples DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=691b9a719fd954f32bb66fc4e18b6089)**

```
-- Exemplo de multiplicação usando o valor atual e o valor anterior de 'coluna'
LAG(coluna) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id ASC) * coluna AS multiplicacao
```

## Original

No `SQL Server` você poderia usar as [**tabelas mágicas**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables) quando usando *triggers*.

No entanto, normalmente, você precisaria de tabelas de *log* para o funcionamento normal do seu sistema, caso seja necessário resgatar valores anteriores.

Se esse não for o caso, você precisa verificar o *log* de transações/[***transaction log***](https://www.sqlshack.com/beginners-guide-sql-server-transaction-logs/). [**Veja como!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507509/how-to-view-transaction-logs-in-sql-server-2008)

Veja também sobre [***change data capture***](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server).